# How can I toggle classes so that clicking the body will toggle off a dropdown menu and change the background on the remaining item (jquery)?

Tags: jquery, menu, toggleclass

There is a menu dropdown comprised of the expand/collapse button (#client-select) and the dropdown menu (.client-select-dd). The menu itself works just fine except that I want it to also be collapsible if the user clicks anywhere outside the menu instead of specifically having to click the button again.

Initially the menu is collapsed, so the first click changes the background on the menu button(#client-select) and makes the dropdown options visible(.client-select-dd). This first click also adds a class to the body(.client-deactivate). Clicking on (#client-select) again collapses the menu and restores the button image-background.

In my mind, clicking on the body while the menu is open (and has the class ".client-deactivate") should collapse the menu and remove .client-deactivate, but clicking on the body does absolutely nothing. Thanks for any help all of you can provide.

```
$("#client-select").click (function() {
  $("body").toggleClass("client-deactivate");
  $(".client-select-close").toggleClass("client-select-open");
  $(".client-select-dd").toggle();
});

$(".client-deactivate").click (function() {
  $(".client-select-open").toggleClass("client-select-close");
  $(".client-select-dd").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out:

$("#client-select").live ('click', function() {
      $("#client-select").addClass("client-select-open");
      $("#client-select").removeClass("client-select-close");
      $(".client-select-dd").css("display", "block");
      $("body").addClass("client-deactivate");
    });

```
$(".client-deactivate").live('click', function() {
  $("#client-select").removeClass("client-select-open");
  $("#client-select").addClass("client-select-close");
  $(".client-select-dd").css("display", "none");
  $("body").removeClass("client-deactivate");
});
```

Comment: I've got very little understanding of ".live". Someone else can probably provide a better explanation of why this works.

Comment: Ah yes, that confirms that the problem was that the body doesn't have the "client-deactivate" class yet, so the event handler wasn't getting bound to the event. I was not aware of .live() -- that's pretty handy!

Apparently, it attaches a handler to an event for an element that WILL GET the selector... In other words, it attaches the event to the element with class name "client-deactivate", even though that element and/or class name doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because when the click handler is first read by the browser, there is no ".client-deactivate" class on the body tag. Also, you don't want to *toggle* anything when you click on the body, because then if the menu is collapsed and you clicked on the body, it would expand the menu. I assume that you only want the body click handler to close the menu if it's already open.

Try changing the second click handler to:

```
$("body").click(function() {
  if($("body").hasClass("client-deactivate") {
    $(".client-select-open").toggleClass("client-select-close");
    $(".client-select-dd").toggle();
    $("body").removeClass("client-deactivate");
  }
});
```

You might also consider replacing these toggle functions with removeClass, just to be sure that clicking on the body doesn't expand the menu... Like if another function were to collapse the menu but doesn't remove the "client-deactivate" class to the body, then clicking on the body would then still have the class name and run the above code, toggling the menu to the open position.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. Any other suggestions?  I've attached the HTML in case that helps:

<div id="client-select" class="client-select-close">
    <ul class="client-select-dd">
      <li><a href="XXX">Option 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="XXX">Option 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="XXX">Option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>